# Why do I get this DBeaver error when importing data from a CSV file?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, dbeaver

I'm a student, and I'm working on a project. The premise is that this program I'm working on takes as input the days (M-F) on which a student is enrolled, the number of hours per day they are enrolled, and which course they are enrolled in. Then, it queries a PostgreSQL database for the amount of progress hours (the "par value" of how long an assignment should take) for each module, and runs an algorithm, outputting the approximate due dates that students should shoot for in order to be done with their course by the deadline (which is set for the entire course rather than for individual assignments).

Now, I've had the database working in the past, but for the next deliverable I am overhauling the program to add support for students selecting their program, which will then populate an option menu with the appropriate courses. To do this, I need to add more test data. In the course of importing additional CSV files into a schema, an error arose:

> Can't load entity attributes
>
> Reason:
> Can't find target attribute [Sequence]

In the CSV file, "Sequence” is the name of one of the columns.

What does this error mean? And, how might I go about resolving it? I have looked over the CSV and I can’t find anything obviously wrong; the heading is there, along with all the associated data. I could in theory create a connection in DBeaver directly with the CSV files rather than importing their data into a database, and I’ve tested doing it that way and it does work as expected, but the Python module I’m using to query the database (psycopg2) doesn’t seem to be able to find it if I do it like that as opposed to using a traditional database (which is how I did it prior to altering my database).

Edit: In response to Adrian's comment, a sample of the CSV data is as follows:

```
PK,Active,Sequence,Name,Number,Hours,Start Date,Stop Date,Modified When,Modified By
183328,TRUE,1,ASP.NET Core Fundamentals,1,2.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183329,TRUE,2,F-Q1,2,3.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183330,TRUE,3,Assignment - Clock-in Station,3,5.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183331,TRUE,4,ASP.NET MVC Fundamentals,4,2.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183332,TRUE,5,MVC-Q1,5,3.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183333,TRUE,6,Wishlist Application,6,5.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183334,TRUE,7,ASP.NET Web APIs,7,2.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183335,TRUE,8,API-Q1,8,3.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183336,TRUE,9,Starchart API,9,5.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
183337,TRUE,10,Dependency Injection,10,2.00,07-01-2020,06-30-2299,06-12-2020 09:09:27 AM,Laraine.Moellendorf
```

I'm not importing this data into an existing table; rather, DBeaver has a feature where one can import a CSV without having an existing table, and a table with matching field headings and data types will be generated to place the data into. So, I do not have a schema to provide.

The DDL that is producing the error is below:

```
CREATE TABLE "Software Development".newtable (
    pk integer NULL,
    active boolean NULL,
    "Sequence" integer NULL,
    "name" varchar(32) NULL,
    "Number" integer NULL,
    hours real NULL,
    "Start Date" varchar(10) NULL,
    "Stop Date" varchar(10) NULL,
    "Modified When" varchar(22) NULL,
    "Modified By" varchar(19) NULL
);
```

In answer to Adrian's last question, DBeaver can link directly to a CSV file rather than importing its data into a table within a database. That was what I meant by it not being a "traditional database".

Comment: Thoughts are that this a lot of verbiage with no real explanation of the problem. To your question add 1) Sample of the CSV data 2) The schema for the table 3) The query you run that gets the error 4) Explain 'traditional database'?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your feedback. My question has been updated to address your points.

Comment: You still need to show the query/code that generates the error. Though at a guess it is not properly quoting the 'Sequence' from the CSV file and it is being lower cased to "sequence" which does not  match the field name "Sequence" in the table.

Comment: I'm not running a query or any code. I'm using DBeaver's GUI to import the CSV data. When I try to preview the results of the data import, the error occurs, and it occurs again if I proceed with the import anyway. Also, I double-checked and the DDL is quoting the "Sequence" properly. I also tried changing the heading in the CSV to "sequence" and the same error occurred, just with "sequence" instead.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it is a case folding issue of some sort. Things to try: 1) Look in the Postgres log to see if shows any useful error. 2) Make a version of the target table where all the field names are lower case and then import to that.

Comment: I will give those a try and report back. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've upgraded to DDeaver version *21.2.0* and everything is working now. I was getting the error trying to export a query to a SQLite table.

So the solution is to upgrade DBeaver.

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be an issue for dBeaver 21.1.4 (https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/13542).  The current workaround is to downgrade to the previous version (21.1.3).

Comment: 100% verified, and still reproduced on version 21.1.5

Comment: Can verify, still occurs in DBeaver 21.1.5. used DB: Postgresql. I downgraded to 21.1.0 and the import worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround has been to use something like "seq_number" for the CSV and column in dBeaver, and then rename the column back to "sequence" after. It's not pretty, but it works. I just did this for the same problem with a column named "depth".

Answer (score -1):

in my case Column deliminater was the problem. I changed `,` to `;`

Answer (score -1):

I am using version Dbeaver 21.2.0. On using file import utility, not all the records are imported.

Total Records in csv file - 9 Lakhs
Records imported - 5 Lakhs records

Earlier i was getting error on import, as data has \ character. On resolving it in file, the records are imported however limited